# When I try to print an element in a certain array it creates a segmentation fault. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault

So as the title suggests, I'm trying to print an element in the array `monthName[12][10]` using the int structure member `allData[i].month` in the code below...

```
void printVerbose(const struct DailyData allData[],int sz){

//print month, day, year and weather data according to # of rows passed in the function

char monthName[12][10] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
int i;

for (i=0;i<sz;i++) {

    float aver = average(allData[i].high,allData[i].low);
    printf("\n%s %d %d %d:  %.1f ", monthName[allData[i].month], allData[i].month, allData[i].day, allData[i].year, aver);
    draw(symbolToDraw(allData[i].condition, aver),20);

}
```

}

However, after printing some lines unsuccessfully like so...

[image: Muh image]

the program terminates and I get an error message. When I compiled this code on linux it mentioned something about a segmentation fault, however I don't know what I'm doing wrong. From what I can tell, `allData[i].month` should produce a regular interger between 1 and 12 (that's certainly the range of numbers it prints in any other situation), so I'm pretty sure that it's nothing to do with the number stored in the structure, yet I'm still getting this issue. Apparently it's something to do with dereferencing the wrong location in the `monthName[][]` array, yet I don't see why this should be the case if the numbers passed are within the acceptable range. Does anybody know why this segfault is happening?

Comment: No, the range of monthName is 0 to 11 inclusive.

Comment: True. I'll have to change it to `allData[i-1].month` in the code

Comment: From what I can see in the code snippet you provide, everything should be ok. I presume, the data you call printVerbose with is already corrupted. See for example, alldata[3].day is 1104989388, as your output shows. Perhaps alldata[4].month is a value outside the range 0-11 and then a segfault occurs

Comment: Can you post all of the code? we'll need to see the implementation of the other functions referenced in that snippet. Plus wherever `printVerbose` is being called.

Comment: The junk being output in your screenshot suggests you've corrupted memory earlier in the program and managed to stumble up to this point before finally falling off the cliff

Comment: To get good answers, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)